# How do I insert data into a relational database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 3 Microsoft SQL Server tables which consist of the following:

- [Customer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFuQJ.png)
- [Training Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsYFI.png)

All 3 tables are related.

I need to insert data into the `Training` table which I can do.

The problem is inserting the `CustomerID` column of the customers table into the training table by only knowing the customer name.

I created a separate class as I will be using this quite a lot in my applications.

```
 public void UpdateDatabase(string sql_query)
 {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql_query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my main class which is used to update my DB.

In my button click even i have the following code.

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        DB NewJob = new DB();

        if (TabControl1.SelectedTab == TabControl1.TabPages["TPTraining"])//If TPTraiing Tab is selected
            {
                try
                {
                    string Customer = TPTcboCustomer.Text;
                    string Product = TPTcboProduct.Text;
                    DateTime DemoDate = TPTdtpDate.Value.Date;
                    string EndResult = TPTtxtEndResult.Text;

                    NewJob.UpdateDatabase("INSERT INTO TrainingDemos(CustomerID, ProductID, DemoDate, EndResult)VALUES('" + Customer + "','" + Product + "','" + DemoDate + "','" + EndResult + "')");
                    MessageBox.Show("Training/Demo Saved Sussesfully");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

The `Customer` variable holds the customer name that i get from the Customer Table. Instead of inserting the Customer Name into the Training Table i must insert the CustomerID.

```
string Customer = TPTcboCustomer.Text;
```

When the form is loaded the TPTcboCustomer combobox control retrieves all customer names from the customer table.

Long story short, how do I insert the `CustomerID` into the training table by only knowing the customer name.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: `INSERT INTO TrainingDemos (...) VALUES ((SELECT CustomerId FROM Customer WHERE name = @CustomerName), @ProductId,...)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do another query to obtain the CustomerID. Once you have that, you can do your insert.

I mean, you need to verify that it's a real customer anyway, right?

I usually prefer to fill a drop down (or similar field) with customers to choose from anyway when there's a finite number of items to choose from. Personally, I'd do an initial query pulling in all of the customers and populate the drop down with those customer objects. Then you just use the selected item's object information to do your insert.

Make `Customer` a strong type:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other properties as desired

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name ?? "<No Name>";
    }
}
```

Once you have that, read in all of your customers and populate the combo box with your list of Customer objects. The `ToString()` will make it display the customer's name in the drop down. Then you just have to do:

```
Customer customer = (Customer)TPTcboCustomer.SelectedItem;
```

Then BLAM-O, you have all of the customer information you need to do your insert.

Comment: There is another form that adds the customers to the customer table. The drop down combo box retrieved the customer names from the customer table and does not allowing editing. Thank you, I am going to try another query and that should do the job.